# Endless Far Cry 2 Malaria Symptoms

Tags: far-cry-2

Playing Far Cry 2 (Fortune's Edition, if it makes any difference), the first few times I took the malaria pills the symptoms (the blurred vision) disappeared pretty soon.

However now I have the malaria symptoms and it seems to be taking forever for the symptoms to go.  In fact I'm finding it painful to play because the constant change in focus (blurred/clear etc.) is giving me a headache.  I took the malaria pills when it started, but it's not stopping.

I am not out of pills. I had run out previously and got a new supply - this is the first attack after the resupply. I took the pills as soon as it started but the symptoms continue.

What do I need to do to clear the symptoms?  I've given it time (in-game and real-world), slept in safe-houses (thinking it might need rest), just sat in a jeep without moving, but it just continues.  It's been over an hour in the game, several in-game days.

Comment: Are you out of pills? You need to do missions for the priest to earn more pills

Comment: After the edit, sounds like a bug.

Comment: @Robotnik I'm not out of pills. Have added this to my question

Comment: @TimmyJim it does seem like it now

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: PC, Windows 10, GOG